# Get value from asp:RadioButton on mouseover

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp:RadioButton inside a asp:GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="RB" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name").ToString() %>' AutoPostBack="true"/>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I can change the background-color like this:

```
$(function () {
 $("[id*=GridView1] td").hover(function () {
    $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("hover_row");
  }
});
```

but I don't know how to extract the value of the RadioButton on mouseover. I tried using the val() function but I always get 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var myval = label[for='" + $(this).find("input:radio").attr("id") + "']").text();
```

Comment: I get error message "Expression expected" if I use FOR= like that

Comment: Missed $(" in that line. Should be                                  var myval = $("label[for='" + $(this).find("input:radio").attr("id") + "']").text()

Comment: Yes that worked. Is there any possibility to change the value for $("label[for='" + $(this).find("input:radio").attr("id") + "']")

Answer (score 0):

I had to use text() and not val():

```
$("td", $(this).closest("tr")).text();
```